# Orion Geo-located query returns Internal Server Error when use longitude values greater than 90 or lesser than -90

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm testing Geo-located queries explained [here](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Geo-located_queries) and when I use a positive values of LatLng 
(Middle of Indian Ocean, China, Australi, West of Canadá, etc) the Context Broker returns Internal Server Error, for example:

This Query:
myorion.local:1026/NGSI10/queryContext?offset=0&limit=100&details=on :

```
{
"restriction":{
    "scopes":[
        {
            "type":"FIWARE_Location",
            "value":{   
                "polygon":{
                    "vertices":[
                        {"latitude":2.811371193331,"longitude":130.078061},
                        {"latitude":13.031027211328,"longitude":130.078061},
                        {"latitude":13.031027211328,"longitude":140.24472766667},
                        {"latitude":2.811371193331,"longitude":140.24472766667}
                        ]
                    }
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    "entities":[
        {"id":".*","type":"Arduino","isPattern":"true"}
    ],
    "attributes":[]
}
```

Returns:

```
{
  "errorCode" : {
    "code" : "500",
    "reasonPhrase" : "Internal Server Error",
    "details" : "collection: orion.entities - query(): { query: { $or: [ { _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Arduino" } ], _id.servicePath: { $exists: false }, location.coords: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: { type: "Polygon", coordinates: [ [ [ 2.811371193331, 130.078061 ], [ 13.031027211328, 130.078061 ], [ 13.031027211328, 140.24472766667 ], [ 2.811371193331, 140.24472766667 ], [ 2.811371193331, 130.078061 ] ] ] } } } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } } - exception: count fails:{ errmsg: "exception: bad geo query", code: 2, ok: 0.0 }"
  }
}
```

The same problem happens for Circle:

```
{
"restriction":{
    "scopes":[
        {
            "type":"FIWARE_Location",
            "value":{
                "circle":{
                    "centerLatitude":0.60024334316097,
                    "centerLongitude":102.58133563829,
                    "radius":610000
                    }
            }
        }
    ]
    },
    "entities":[
        {"id":".*","type":"Arduino","isPattern":"true"}
    ],
    "attributes":[]
}
```

Will return:

```
{
  "errorCode" : {
    "code" : "500",
    "reasonPhrase" : "Internal Server Error",
    "details" : "collection: orion.entities - query(): { query: { $or: [{ _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Arduino" } ], _id.servicePath: { $exists: false }, location.coords: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 0.6002433431609701, 102.58133563829 ], 0.0957463506513891 ] } } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } } - exception: count fails:{ errmsg: "exception: bad geo query", code: 2, ok: 0.0 }"
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that is because of positive values, because aways when I have a positive value in Lat or Lng value i get this erro from Context Broker

> **"collection: orion.entities - query(): { query: { $or: [{ _id.id: /.*/, _id.type: "Arduino" } ], _id.servicePath: { $exists: false }, location.coords: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 0.6002433431609701, 102.58133563829 ], 0.0957463506513891 ] } } }, orderby: { creDate: 1 } } - exception: count fails:{ errmsg: "exception: bad geo query", code: 2, ok: 0.0 }"**

- Orion Version: 0.14.0
- MongoDB Version:  2.6.3
- CentOS 6.5

Comment: Which MongoDB version is Orion using? Please, edit your question to add this information.

Comment: While I get some time to test with MongoDB 2.6.3... Could you test the same scenario with MongoDB 2.4.9 (the reference MongoDB version for 0.14.0), please? Start with an empty database to remove any inter-test interference, please (see https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Delete_complete_database)

Comment: At mooment I'm testing overloads and limits, and I have a mass of data than I can't delete by now.
How can I backup safety it(to delete) and leater restores my data?

Comment: LeonanCarvalho: I didn't know it was difficult to test on your side. No problem, I will do the test.

Comment: The problems seems to be due to a bug. More detail on https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion versions previous to 0.14.0 have a [known bug](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/461) that avoids to use queries with longitude greater than 90 degrees (or lesser than -90 degrees). The bug has been already fixed in the develop branch in code repository, to be included in Orion 0.14.1 release.

Thanks to Leonan Carvalho for helping debugging this problem!

Comment: Thanks!
I hope this problem help some other users!
:D